# Adding to a plugin with wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress

I'm having major problems with this. Basically, I need to add a "url" field to the event management plugin with wordpress. My client wants to be able to add a url to their event so it can be clicked and viewed for more information on the event. I've looked through everything and im having problems understanding the wordpress file structure. I tried to add my own field to the event editor, database and front end but i dont know where wordpress posts the data to so i cant receive the variable. If i could get the variable, i could probably figure out how to use $wpdb relatively simply. but for that matter, i dont know where i should use that. where is the file that makes all those calls? i shouldnt have a problem getting the data from the database.

**Edit**

My problem, as described, was solved by installing another plugin called PODS. the only solution to adding functionality to a plugin, as in other fields, is to write your own plugin (as far as im aware). PODS solved my problem. It allowed me to add another field to the front of the event management form and saved it to the database. I still had to retrieve it from the database and display it on the front myself with php, but it was a much easier task than i expected it to be. If anybody wants to add extra fields to a plugin in wordpress, PODS is what i'd suggest. It's also free.

Comment: Seems like you need to do a bit more research... Try solving the problem with what you can find, then come back with the piece of code that failed and post links to mentioned plugins and you might get people interested in answering your question.

Comment: did your client hire you? or S.O?

Comment: ive been researching since 9:30 this morning and im at a complete loss. i dont understand the file structure at all. ive read tutorials about writing my own plugin so as to understand the structure better but im still completely lost on it. im at a dead end. all im asking for is somebody to point me in the right direction. possibly explain how wordpress is structured, any good tutorials or information or anything that might help me get out of this rut

Comment: im a php programmer and im interviewing. im trying to see if i can take on plugins because ive never worked with wordpress before yesterday. ive done a TON of research in the past 2 days though.

Comment: Then maybe you should you start with something simpler to learn how WordPress works. The Codex is the best resource to get started. If you're already an experienced PHP programmer then reading through the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) manual and understanding the basics concepts should be fairly quick.

Comment: that seems potentially helpful. thanks, im reading that now. any other suggestions..?

Comment: You could also join us on IRC. Freenode channel #wordpress :-)